# How to get IP adress with WINSOCK ? c++

Tags: c++, macos, ip, ip-address, winsock

I'm not familiar with networks and etc so I dont  get how to use it, so if anyone can help me how to get ip adress of my  computer with it and I also have to get MAC adress too.

Comment: [`getaddrinfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

WinSock is a Windows-specific API.  Most socket APIs in general do not provide information about local IP/MAC addresses.  You *might* be able to use `getaddrinfo()` to query the IP addresses for `localhost`, but that would be implementation-specific whether it works or not, and it would not include MAC addresses anyway.

On Windows, the correct way to get the IP and MAC addresses for the local machine is to use [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx) or [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) to enumerate the local NICs.

On POSIX-based platforms, including OSX, you can use [`getifaddrs()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) to get the local IP addresses (family `AF_INET/6`) and MAC addresses (family `AF_LINK`).